# Difference between finding a position using GDAL or just using a binary grid

Tags: python, gdal

I need to randomly access a series of points in some 1/3 arc second DEM files (GEOTIFFs). If I try to do this in python with the GDAL lib, when I shift from a band in one geotiff to another, it takes several seconds even if I preload the bands. So, I have pulled the bands out of the files and made my own binary files by reading the band data into numpy array, then flattening the array and storing it in a binary file. If I know my x and y, I can use the formula:

val = dataset[(y*10812) + x]
where dataset is my numpy array and 10812 is the number of points in each row.

I can preload the files I need by determining the extents of the area I will be searching and then finding the x,y vals of the array in a particular 1x1 degree file since I know the pixel size of 1/3 arc second (0.000092592592526 degrees). I determine my x and y from a lat/lon point by first determining the start position of the tile, then getting the difference between the lat/lon point and the start point and dividing the difference in decimal degrees by 0.000092592592526. Here is an example:
For point 32.99544068369076 -96.99801375384197 I am in a file with start point (upper left of 33,-97).
the differences are:
ydiff = 0.00455931630924 for lat
xdiff = 0.00198624615803 for lon

dividing these by my 1/3 arc sec gives me:
x = 0.00198624615803 / 0.000092592592526 = 21.451
y = 0.00455931630924 / 0.000092592592526 = 49.241

we round the x down since the 1/3 arc sec pixels are referenced to the left and round y up since the pixels are referenced at the top to get 21,50
applying this to our formula to find the byte position in the file I get:

val = dataset[(50*10812) + 21] which in my file gives me a value of 162.33952

BUT when I use GDAL from the command line for the same set of lat lon values I get a value of 166.04512. If I run a search on the band for the GDAL elevation, I get an x = 27 and y = 55. I can confirm this by running the GDAL command line again with x and y instead of WGS84 lat lons and I get the same elevation of 166.04512. If I repeat with different lat lons, I'm always close, but off anywhere from 1 to 7 positions on each axis. It's not a lot, but concerns me that I can't come up with the same values.

So, my question is, why are they different? Is my math on finding the point in my array wrong? The pixel size from the geotiff is 0.000092592592526 but this corresponds to 10800 not the 10812 that the file lists. I know there is overlap in the tiles, but would this really make a difference? Can anyone provide an explanation as to the difference?